# Create type with double symbol

Tags: haskell

The List type is created with

```
data [] a = [] | a : [a]
```

But I can't create my own type with the same structure:

```
data %% a = %% | a : %a%
```

> error: parse error on input `%%'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The List type is created with
>
> ```
> data [] a = [] | a : [a]
> ```

No, it isn't. If you look at [the source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html) (for GHC; other compilers may do it differently), it says

```
data [] a = MkNil
```

but <s>this is just a marker for the compiler</s> (not even this, see chepner's comment). This is because

```
data [] a = [] | a : [a]
```

isn't legal syntax in Haskell.

What is true is that list works *as if* it were defined this way: it's entirely equivalent to

```
data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)
```

except for the names.

Comment: Even `data [] a = MkNil` is a pseudo-code comment, contained as it is inside a `#if 0 ... #endif` block. `[]` as a type constructor and data constructor is special-cased, defined *by* the language but not definable *in* the language.

Comment: Oops. I did see that `#if 0` but didn't check its scope. (And was slightly surprised that parser would handle `[]` as a type name; clearly not enough.)

Answer (score 1):

Type and constructor names must either be alphanumeric names, starting with uppercase

```
data MyType a b = K a | L b a
```

or be symbolic infix operators, starting with `:`

```
data a :** b = K a | b :+-& a
```

Both types above are perfectly isomorphic: we only replaced `MyType` with the infix `:**` and `L` with the infix `:+-&`.

Also note that infixes must be binary, i.e. take two arguments. Alphanumeric names do not have such constraint (e.g. `K` above only takes one argument).

List syntax `[]` is specially handled by the compiler, similarly to `(,),(,,),...` for tuples. Only `:` follows the general rule (perhaps incidentally).